# Deploy a webapp shared library on weblogic 12C

Tags: java, weblogic, weblogic12c

I'm trying to migrate my shared libs built against weblogic 10.3.x against weblogic 12C.
I succeeded to deploy the ear shared libraries. Unfortunately, the deployment of webapp sharedlibraries always fails withe the following error :

```
Erreur Impossible d'accéder à l'application sélectionnée.
Erreur Exception in AppMerge flows' progression
Erreur Exception in AppMerge flows' progression
Erreur Unable to transform version 2.4 web application namespace to version 2.5
```

My typical webapp shared library have the following content

```
/WEB-INF/
---------web.xml
---------lib
------------ my libraries
```

The content of my web.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<web-app 
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        version="2.5">

</web-app>
```

What should I change ?

Thanks in advance for your help

Regards

Comment: Do you have a weblogic.xml?

Comment: No, I only have a web.xml file. It works on 10.3.x WLS servers. Is it mandatory now to have a weblogic.xml file  ?

Comment: No, weblogic.xml is not required. I am just try to find where the AppMerge is coming from. If you deploy the webapp shared library as a regular web application instead, does it throw any error?

Comment: I can't choose. The error occurs before I can choose between a library deployment or an application deployment.

Comment: It is a weird problem. Is your domain upgrade in place or a brand new 12c domain? If it is the former, would you please make sure all the tmp/stage/cache directories are removed under the each managed server directory?

Comment: It's a new server  /domain. We are trying to migrate our legacy projects using both ear shared libs and webapps shared libs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did not pay attention to your namespace defintion earlier. Try this in the `web.xml`

```
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
```